# DataGridView row repositioning

Tags: datagridview, rows

Is there a simple way to swap the position of two rows in an unbound 
DataGridView? I am using it to display an ordered list, where I want the 
up/down arrow keys to shuffle a row up and down the grid, but I can't see 
any way to reposition a row within the grid without completely repopulating 
it, which seems excessive. The Index value for a row is read-only.

Answer (score 4):

to move a row, use 
DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt 
and then 
DataGridView.Rows.Insert

Comment: +1 for supplying an answer to your own question.  There should be a badge for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data bound via BindingSource (and you store the binding source in a variable called bindingSource), you can call bindingSource.RemoveAt(x) and bindingSource.insert(x) and the data (for example, your List) and the rows of the DataGridView will swap for you.