# C# Shuffling DataGridView Rows

Tags: c#, datagridview, shuffle

I have a DataGridView with thousands of records which I programmatically added them. There is no datasource involved in this case. Now I want to shuffle the records each time I click a button. How can that be achieved?

Comment: Shuffled in what way? Randomly indexed?

Comment: `OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1048334/451590), you can use [`DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.removeat.aspx) and `DataGridView.Rows.Insert` to reposition rows in an unbound DataGridView. You can generate a set of random integer indexes to copy, remove and insert elsewhere in the table to recreate 'shuffling'.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()). Depending on the system, your Guid could be sequential. **GUIDs are meant to be unique, not random.** To shuffle a collection, you can call sort and passes in a Comparator that returns result at random (e.g. Random(-1, 1)).